# Compare Stable-Baselines3 vs. Tianshou

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, stable-baselines

What would you recommend between [Stable-Baselines3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3) and [Tianshou](https://github.com/thu-ml/tianshou) for applied research in Reinforcement Learning?

Can anyone provide a comparison of the strengths and weaknesses of each library? Or at least some criteria for choosing one over the other?

It seams like Tianshou is much more flexible and generalist but I have not been able to find a benchmark that clearly establishes this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.